# In a flat spin, does the F-16 use its rudder deflection against the rotation for recovering?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, pilot-technique, f-16, rudder

If the H-tail is used in recovery from the flat spin, is the rudder used for stopping the yaw or beta of the F-16?

I know that it is surely used for inverted flat spin, but I believe that the rudder is blanked by the H-tails in upright spin and is not effective.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to have the rudder deflection because the huge amount of AOA and control law take that in consideration and cancel (fadeaway) the pilot rudder inputs.Activating the MPO the slabs moved  max in order to get the nose down to lower AOA and after that we can get responses from the rudder .https://www.flightglobal.com/f-16-spin-recovery-technique-invented/15027.article

Comment: Is there a source for this information?

Comment: It does provide an answer to the question, and provides detail.

Comment: I have a really hard time believing that this is really true. But if is-- great answer!  (But please give some source to back it up.)  And if it's not-- then never mind.

Comment: https://www.flightglobal.com/f-16-spin-recovery-technique-invented/15027.article

Comment: Groovy link, but I'm not seeing the connection to your answer.  All I see is something about "differential horizontal tail" (deflection)..

Comment: PS what the heck is an "inlet store" anyway?  They are shoving those things up the nose of the poor airplane?  Like a nose ring (groovy, or not.)??

Comment: Traditionally the spin is broken by these methods : applied max rudder against the spin , idle the engine and neutral the stick ,then pull up from the nose down.In F 16is the decoupling the FBW and  push and pull on the stick with no rudder deflection above the 29 AOA.

Comment: Sniper pod or another under the inlet , number 5 and 7 pylon

Comment: "In F 16is the decoupling the FBW and push and pull on the stick with no rudder deflection above the 29 AOA" -- if this idea is really true that rudder deflection goes to zero above 29 degrees AoA (and I'm not disputing it), you should incorporate it more specifically into your answer, preferably with a source.